# Porting VB.Net .NetFramework DLL to an ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to port a VB.Net .NetFramework DLL to an ASP.Net 5 c# project.

I have compiled it to Framework 4.6.1 and produced a nuget package using the command line tool.

The installation into the project appears to succeed according to the IDE output window.

However when I compile I get these errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1002  The dependency <package id/version> in project does not support framework DNX,Version=v4.5.1.   
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1002  The dependency <package id/version>  in project does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.    
Error   NU1002  The dependency <package id/version>  in project does not support framework DNX,Version=v4.5.1.  
Error   NU1002  The dependency <package id/version>  in project does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
```

Any ideas how I can go about resolving these.  I have a sizeable VB.Net solution which I need to get run under .Net Core on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

It is because Visual Basic .NET still not supported by .NET Core.

If you look at following link https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap it is going to support in future. It is in their todo work list.